# setting a button disabled if there is some error for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am generating some rows using ng-repeat, I am showing error for each row based on certain condition. Upto that my code is working fine. Now If I got any error I want to make a button disabled that is outside the scope of ng-repeat. How can I do that?

html code

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.phone" />
    <div ng-if="validateRow(item)">Here is my error</div>
</div>
<button ng-disabled="I want to disabl this if there is some error for the above ng-repeat">Click </button>
```

js code

```
$scope.validateRow = function(item) {
    return true or false based on item values
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should be enough

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
<input type="text" ng-model="item.phone" />
<div ng-show="validateRow(item)">Here is my error</div>
</div>
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled">Click </button>



function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.itemList = [{"name": "", "phone": "123"},{"name": "", "phone": "456"},{"name": "", "phone": "789"}];

$scope.disable= false;

$scope.validateRow = function(item) {

$scope.disable= false;
    for(var c =0; c < $scope.itemList.length; c++){

        if($scope.itemList[c].name != "abc"){

            $scope.disable = true;
            break;
        }
    }

   return item.name != 'abc';
}
```

}

Update with the link working

http://jsfiddle.net/LXAt7/125/

Comment: It will not work if the error shown for first row and the last row has no error!

Comment: It will work. The variable will be settled only once to true. So, if there are some error it will disable the button as you asked.

Comment: Yes its working but this operation is too intensive! typing anything is calling the validate method many times

Answer (score 0):

In view

```
<button ng-disabled="disable">Click </button>
```

In controller,

```
$scope.disable= false;
$scope.validateRow = function(item) {
   if(true based on item values) // if your going to return true
      $scope.disable= true;
   }
   return true or false based on item values
}
```

Comment: Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/LXAt7/124/ Try to enter abc in all text boxes of first column, you will see error is not displayed but button still disabled